# MUI v5 broke default TextField behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

When we finish writing a comment in the TextField , the TextField has focus and nothing happens when we click Done. The first click removes focus from the TextField. A second press of the button ends the process.
[image]

```
    <TextField
      id={'generalComment'}
      value={comment}
      label="Общий комментарий"
      multiline
      minRows={7}
      onChange={onCommentChange}
      onBlur={onCommentSubmit}
      variant="outlined"
      margin="normal"
      required
      error={!!commentError}
      helperText={commentError}
      InputLabelProps={{
        shrink: true,
      }}
      inputProps={{maxLength: 2000}}
      className={classNames({[classes.importantField]: !comment})}
    />
```

onBlur works fine if focus is removed from the field. But the button's onClick doesn't work on the first click on it.

**onBlur intercepts the click event on the UI buttons and prevents those events from firing.**

How to write onBlur so that the buttons work the first time even when the focus is on the TextField?

```
    const onCommentSubmit= event => {
       console.log("BLUR");
       const value = event.target.value.trim();
       setGeneralComment(value);
       onGeneralCommentSubmit(value);
    };
```

**Expected behavior**
Buttons are expected to work on first click. It is not logical to press the button several times.

**Steps to reproduce**
Steps:

1. Creating a component that has a TextField and a button.
2. Creating Click Handlers
3. Fill in the field
4. Click on the button

**Context**
I would like the button to be pressed the first time. So that the focus on the field does not block the user interface.

my environment
`npx @mui/envinfo`

```
System:                                                   
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.19044                               
  Binaries:                                                 
    Node: 16.13.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE        
    Yarn: 1.22.17 - ~\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.CMD
    npm: 8.5.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  Browsers:
    Chrome: Google Chrome
    Edge: Spartan (44.19041.1266.0), Chromium (99.0.1150.36)
  npmPackages:
    @emotion/react: 11.8.1 => 11.8.1
    @emotion/styled: 11.8.1 => 11.8.1
    @mui/base:  5.0.0-alpha.70
    @mui/core: 5.0.0-alpha.54 => 5.0.0-alpha.54
    @mui/icons-material: 5.4.4 => 5.4.4
    @mui/lab: 5.0.0-alpha.71 => 5.0.0-alpha.71
    @mui/material: 5.4.4 => 5.4.4
    @mui/private-theming:  5.4.4
    @mui/styled-engine:  5.4.4
    @mui/styles: 5.4.4 => 5.4.4
    @mui/system:  5.4.4
    @mui/types:  7.1.2
    @mui/utils:  5.4.4
    @types/react:  17.0.39
    react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2
    react-dom: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2
    typescript:  4.6.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you change state too many times.

I wouldn't trim the value in onBlur function. Let the user type whatever he wants and trim the value just before submitting (inside `onGeneralCommentSubmit` function if I assumed good.. I also assumed that `setGeneralComment` is state update for `comment`). In this way, you will not invoke rerender after onBlur. Of course, it depends on what is inside `onGeneralCommentSubmit`.

```js
<TextField
      id={'generalComment'}
      value={comment}
      (...)
      onChange={onCommentChange}
      onBlur={onGeneralCommentSubmit}
      (...)
    />

const onGeneralCommentSubmit = (event) => {
  if (comment) {
    const value = comment.trim();
    // do something with the value
  }
};
```

Submitting form onBlur is probably not a good practice :)